# when i press button in MFC(CButton), not change value in real time. I'm use sql server

Tags: c++, mfc, oledb, listcontrol

I'm use sql server 2014 and visual studio 2015 community 
I working on MFC DB Program(single document and OLE DB) but faced big trouble

Problem is when i change DB value in use by MFC button value isn't change in real time 
when i pressed refresh button in editor, change value 
how can i change value in real time?

below is code and picture

update button code

```
void CTouhouJGSView::OnBnClickedButtonUpdate()
{
    // TODO: 여기에 컨트롤 알림 처리기 코드를 추가합니다.
    CCommand<CDynamicAccessor> cmd;

    CString strQuery = _T("UPDATE dbo.TouhouTable SET 능력 = 'ewrer' WHERE id = 1");

    cmd.Open(m_pSet->m_session, strQuery, NULL);
    cmd.Close();
    AddAllRecord();
}
```

AddAllRecord() function

```
void CTouhouJGSView::AddAllRecord()
{
    CString strTemp = _T("");

    m_pSet->MoveFirst();
    m_List.DeleteAllItems();
    int i = 0;
    do {
        strTemp.Format(_T("%4d"), m_pSet->m_Id);
        m_List.InsertItem(i, strTemp, 0);
        m_List.SetItemText(i, 1, m_pSet->m_section);
        m_List.SetItemText(i, 2, m_pSet->m_name);
        m_List.SetItemText(i, 3, m_pSet->m_title);
        m_List.SetItemText(i, 4, m_pSet->m_species);
        m_List.SetItemText(i, 5, m_pSet->m_living);
        m_List.SetItemText(i, 6, m_pSet->m_spell);
        i++;
    } while (m_pSet->MoveNext() == S_OK);

    m_pSet->MoveFirst();
}
```

and program picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Lpl.png)

EDIT :  definition of m_pSet

```
#pragma once
#include "afxcmn.h"
#include "afxwin.h"

class CTouhouJGSSet;

class CTouhouJGSView : public COleDBRecordView
{
    protected: // serialization에서만 만들어집니다.
    CTouhouJGSView();
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CTouhouJGSView)

public:
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum{ IDD = IDD_TOUHOUJGS_FORM };
#endif
    CTouhouJGSSet* m_pSet; //here

// 특성입니다.
public:
    CTouhouJGSDoc* GetDocument() const;
```

EDIT2: class CTouhouJGSSet change part

```
//class CTouhouJGSSet : public CTable<CAccessor<CTouhouJGSSetAccessor> >
class CTouhouJGSSet : public CCommand<CAccessor<CTouhouJGSSetAccessor> >
{

......

HRESULT OpenRowset(DBPROPSET *pPropSet = NULL)
{
    //HRESULT hr = Open(m_session, L"dbo.TouhouTable", pPropSet);
    CString strSQL = _T("select * from dbo.TouhouTable");
    HRESULT hr = Open(m_session, strSQL, pPropSet);
```

and OnInitialUpdate() function

```
void CTouhouJGSView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
,,,,,
    COleDBRecordView::OnInitialUpdate();
    AddColumn();       //additional function
    AddAllRecord();    //additional function
}
```

EDIT 3: i say refresh button 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkQRi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the way `m_pSet` is filled with data. You have to refresh it or recreate before `AddAllRecord();`

```
void CTouhouJGSView::OnBnClickedButtonUpdate()
{
    // TODO: 여기에 컨트롤 알림 처리기 코드를 추가합니다.
    CCommand<CDynamicAccessor> cmd;
    CString strQuery = _T("UPDATE dbo.TouhouTable SET 능력 = 'ewrer' WHERE id = 1");
    cmd.Open(m_pSet->m_session, strQuery, NULL);
    cmd.Close();

    cmd.OpenRowset(m_pSet); //<-- you can try to close it first, if its already opened
    AddAllRecord();
}
```

Comment: Show me definition of `m_pSet`

Comment: The `m_pSet` object seem to not refresh as MS documentation says. Show how its initialized and filled with DB data. Recreating object, and filling it with data should help.

Comment: You change value using button (UPDATE?), and you dont see that value is changed untill you press refresh button? Where is the refresh button?

Comment: i upload refresh button image and when i first debug, List control isn't show changed value to me  but second debug List control is show changed value to me

Comment: This is Microsoft Sql Server Management Grid. It does not refresh everytime values are changed. Everything seem to be ok.

Comment: i use OLE DB Is this cause?

Comment: Try executing OpenRecordset before AddAllRecord, or find way that m_pSet is created and used to load data. Then call these methods.

Comment: `HRESULT hr = Open(m_session, strSQL, pPropSet);` executes statement and stores data in pPropSet object. Check my answer. Im not sure about the parameter given as pPropSet but according to way u fill data in listview, i assume it has to be the container of data returned by `OpenRowset`

Comment: `m_pSet` should have it. Try `m_pSet->OpenRowset() `.  I'f it won't help try `m_pSet->OpenRowset (m_pSet)`.  If it won't work the I won't be able to help without more application code.